# ActionBar Fragment view with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have an app with 1 Activity which has 3 tabs created with ActionBar Sherlock. One of these tabs has a ListFragment which is then replaced with other Fragments when an item is chosen.

The problem I'm having is when the views are re-created (such as orientation change). I can't work out how to stay on the Fragment that is currently active when the orientation changes. For example, if I'm viewing a Fragment then change the orientation, it will go back to the ListFragment.

I understand why it does this, because it's calling the onCreate in the main activity but I have no idea how to get the last fragment back. I've looked on the Android developers page, Googled it countless times and looked at almost every stackoverflow question related to it but I just don't understand how to do it in my app.
It would be great if someone could explain how I can keep the fragment when the view is reloaded.

Here is my onCreate...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Set up navigation bar to show tabs
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Add tabs to navigation bar
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Sermons")
                .setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Downloads")
                .setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Contact")
                .setTabListener(this));
}
```

OnSaveInstanceState...

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
```

OnRestoreInstanceState...

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}
```

OnTabSelected...

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    String tabText = (String) tab.getText();

    if (tabText == "Audio") {
        fragment = new AudioCategoryFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    } else if (tabText == "Downloads") {
        fragment = new DownloadsFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    } else if (tabText == "Contact") {
        fragment = new ContactsFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: use the bundle to store the informations you need. Here, it look like you need at least to store the type of fragment you want to display the next time the activity is created.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So in the Fragment, I save that Fragment type into a Bundle, then in the activity how do I display that when the activity is created? In the RestoreInstanceState I guess?

Comment: nope :) . onCreate will be called each time the Activity is recreated.
So you have to test the content of the bundle. if it is empty, it is the first creation of the Activity and you can keep the same logic. If not, it means that you have to recreate a Fragment and the bundle should contain the necessary data to do so.